# What happens if you've already found the item an old map leads to?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

When I pick up an Old Map an item location in the Depths gets marked on my map. However, I've noticed that I can alternatively find these times without a map while exploring.

What happens if I find an item in the Depths, then afterwards I open a chest that would have contained the Old Map revealing the item's location?

Answer (score 35):

Because I explored the depths more extensively early on than the sky, I actually just had this occur. When you pick up the Old Map, it still opens up the map of the depths in the general area where it *would* place the 'X', and instead of placing the 'X', pops up a message that says something along the lines of "you've already collected the treasure from this map", and simply closes the map without taking any further action.